# `airmon-ng` not working

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

When I run `airmon-ng start wlan0` I get the following message posted below, then my WiFi is not working. I then run `ifconfig` and I see my wireless device it active but no connection. The following processes never affected `airmon-ng`so im puzzled (as always). Oh and I have the following version of Aircrack-ng:

> `Aircrack-ng 1.2 rc1 r2459 - (C) 2006-2014 Thomas d'Otreppe`

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

  PID Name
  591 avahi-daemon
  594 avahi-daemon
 1089 NetworkManager
 1166 wpa_supplicant
 1882 dhclient

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       iwlwifi     Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)command failed: Input/output error (-5)

        (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]wlan0mon)
        (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlan0)
```

My results for `ifconfig`

```
whisper@Silence:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2189727 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:2189727 (2.1 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXScope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:896 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:432258 (432.2 KB)  TX bytes:161018 (161.0 KB)
```

Comment: You certainly must have been [here](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng), but in case you did not, that might help. Although... I have been trying to follow the instructions but my monitor still does not connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was a `libpcap` issuse as the new versions have bugs or a are programmed to not allow you to use `reaver` the solution is to downgraded to:

`libpcap0.8-dev_1.4.0-2_amd64`

`libpcap0.8_1.4.0-2_amd64`

After you downgrade it is important you avoid any upgrades or before upgrading, check upgrade files for `libpcap`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the use of `wlanXmon` instead of `monX` is not an error. This is a new feature, added with the current version of Aircrack-ng.

Secondly, despite the effects those processes may have had before you updated, a network process is now interfering with your Aircrack installation. You can fix this easily by running `sudo airmon-ng check kill all`, but be aware that this is very likely to temporarily break your networking settings menu.

It is better to learn how to use this new version, rather than downgrading, because downgrading will inevitably bring a downpour of broken dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Is sounds like this has worked for you in the past, so the problem may be the version you are running. You said you had Aircrack-ng 1.2 rc1 r2459

According to the log posted, it appears there was a problem running a command involving wifi

```
 phy0    wlan0       iwlwifi     Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)command failed: Input/output error (-5)
```

I am on Ubuntu 14.10, with a different wifi adapter. I installed airckrack with apt-get. The version installed was  Aircrack-ng 1.2 beta3. When I run

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

everything works as it should.

[image]

```
 ifconfig

 wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
      inet addr:192.168.1.70  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2216:d8ff:fefa:a073/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:105900 (105.9 KB)  TX bytes:49607 (49.6 KB)

 mon0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:100716 errors:0 dropped:100857 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:126631342 (126.6 MB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

So I guess what I am getting at is you can give the version I am using a try, or like I said, it sounds like you had this working before, so if you recently updated to the version your using now, maybe for now you will need to downgrade to a working version.

Comment: I had a problem with the previous version also and i was instructed to update aircrack it worked until I restarted the computer... sigh :(

Comment: so I installed some `libpcap0.8_1.4.0-2_amd64.deb` and got the `command failed: Input/output error (-5)` to stop the device goes into monitor mode on `wlan0mon` but wifi is disconnnected (strange) when I run `airodump-ng wlan0mon` it starts the scan then runs for a minute or 2 then the system logs me out??? why? I am once again "puzzled"... Help!! :( @geoffmcc

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you on? And shouldn't you be using sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 to get monitor mode.  P.S. Where all those vmnet's in ifconfig before you started?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, no I'm not sure I cant really remember when I installed VMplayer... I am going to uninstall them.

Comment: I uninstalled VMware player and its virtual network devices.... problem persist.

Comment: Let me do some more research and get back to you, unless someone else gets you going first. One question though, now you removed vm, restart and does ifconfig only show lo, eth0 and wlan0 now

Comment: Yes it that is the result of `ifconfig`

Comment: @geofmcc anything yet???

Comment: @geoffmcc The issue is the change in airmon-ng - v1.2 rc2 from airmon-ng to airmon-zc http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=changelog

Comment: @Kurupt This is the only current fix for Intel cards I have found: Downgrade to rc1. After downloading run `make && sudo make install` https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/releases/tag/1.2-rc1

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above, the only fix was shutting down the network-manager process.`service network-manager stop` **BEFORE** running `airmon-ng start wlan0` after the Error "**(mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlan0)**" went away and i was able to run *`airodump-ng`* without any issues.
Kali 2.0
I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method that may or may not work (found in some video-tutorial on stackskills.com). It worked for me on a recently downloaded Kali-Linux iso.

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 # shows if wlan0 is now in monitor-mode

airodump-ng wlan0 # Should show the available wlan-networks
```